# Custom Tag Helper not working in ASP.Net Core MVC

Tags: c#, razor, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-2.0, asp.net-core-tag-helpers

I am using Asp.Net Core MVC and i am trying to create a new Tag Helper Attribute but tag helper attribute is not working and no intelliSense is showing up on my razor view. I don't know what i am doing wrong.

Tag Helper code

```
namespace Vue.js_Hello_World.Helpers
{
    [HtmlTargetElement("input", Attributes = "asp-line")]
    public class CustomTagHelper: TagHelper
    {
        [HtmlAttributeName("asp-line")]
        public string ID { get; set; }
        public override void Process(TagHelperContext context, TagHelperOutput output)
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(ID))
            {
                output.Attributes.SetAttribute("id", ID + new Guid());
            }
            base.Process(context, output);
        }
    }
}
```

_ViewImports.cshtml

```
@using Vue.js_Hello_World
@using Vue.js_Hello_World.Models
@addTagHelper *, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers
@addTagHelper *, Vue.js_Hello_World
```

VueDetail.cshtml (this is a partial view)

```
@model Vue.js_Hello_World.Models.VueJsTestModelDetail

<td style="width:200px;">@Model.DetailId</td>
<td style="width:200px;">@Model.Id</td>
<td >
    <input type="hidden" asp-for="DetailId" asp-line ="DetailId"/>
    <input type="hidden" asp-for="Id" />
    <input type="text" asp-for="Email" class="form-control-sm" style="width:250px;"/>
</td>
```

Comment: Why is `Vue` your root namespace?  Are you using Vue?

Comment: A possible reason : your `AssemblyName` is not `Vue.js_Hello_World`.

Comment: I am just testing some things with VueJS. This is just a helloWorld project that involves custom tag helpers and VueJS. I suppose having Vue in namespace should not matter in case of tag helpers. I also tried it with "SampleNamespace" as well.

Comment: @SaudNasir What's the name of your assembly ?

Comment: @itminus it is Vue.js_Hello_World

Comment: @SaudNasir Is there a minimal demo that reproduces the same issue ?

Answer (score 0):

There is a whitespace between the attribute and the equals sign.

This

```cs
<input type="hidden" asp-for="DetailId" asp-line ="DetailId"/>
```

should look like this

```cs
<input type="hidden" asp-for="DetailId" asp-line="DetailId"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve this by matching the name of HtmlTargetElement and name of the TagHelper class. I just needed to replace `CustomTageHelper` with `inputTagHelper` which was actually the name of the HtmlTargetElement.